# MatrixTransform's matrix looks transposed to me

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, matrix, transformation

This is more a question of curiosity why MatrixTransform the way it is, rather than a real problem.

MSDN gives the affine transformation matrix of MatrixTransform like this:

```
     m11  m12  0
A := m21  m22  0
     offX offY 1
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrixtransform(v=VS.100).aspx

To transform a point, you use it this way: `x' = xTA`. This is different from what I would expect - `x' = Ax`, which uses this matrix:

```
     m11  m12  offX
A := m21  m22  offY
       0    0     1
```

I realize that this makes no difference for the implementation of MatrixTransform, but I wonder if am missing some insight here. Does anyone know why the transformation matrix is specified the way it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a convention to have the matrix row-major instead of column major. Most computer graphics systems follow this convention.